# Stomp SockJs client + server Spring

Tags: spring, websocket, npm, stomp, sockjs

I have a spring boot application, i use npm and webpack. I want to start a websocket to send some messages from server to client. My server is built with java, and the client with javascript using stomp and sockjs.
Here's my code:
Client:

```
    socket = new SockJS('/myWebSocketEndPoint');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect("","", function (frame) {
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/notification', function (notificationBody) {
                  alert(angular.fromJson(notificationBody.body).content);
    });
  });
}
```

Server:
Config:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
    public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/myWebSocketEndPoint").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    @SendTo("/topic/notification")
    public String sendToMenuItems(String menuItem)  {
          return menuItem;
    }
```

The problem is: when i want to run my application, it not makes upgrade with websocket (it seems that server is not working, or client not find server). So the upgrade request remains pending. If i use:

```
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/sockjs-client").withSockJS();
    }
```

and

```
    socket = new SockJS('/sockjs-client');
```

the upgrade works, but not connect and subscribe. Why if i use the second configuration my application (partially) works and if i use first configuration it doesn't? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
stompClient.connect("","", function (frame) {
...
```

with:

```
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have @MessageMapping("/sockjs-client") over the controller.
try with this annotation along with @sendUser annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `setAllowedOriginPatterns` to make this setup work

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/live");
        registry.addEndpoint("/live").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```